# Wikipedia redirect target containing a # symbol

Tags: android, http, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am doing direct queries to wikipedia's website via an android app.

However, sometimes when I get "REDIRECT" queries, and my redirect suggestion has a # sign in it, I don't really know how to handle it. I know I can just throw everything out past the # sign, but that means I'm looking up something that is relatively unimportant.

Here is an example link;
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Poof_(The_Fairly_OddParents)&format=json

I can just redirect to List_of_The_Fairly_OddParents_characters, but I want to know if there is anything useful I can do with the "#Poof" because I'm sure that the information is there for a reason.

I could not find anything on MediaWiki APIs.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: You might want to use the [`redirects` parameter](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Resolving_redirects): http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Poof_(The_Fairly_OddParents)&format=jsonfm&exintro=1&redirects

Comment: What do you want to do with the query results at all? Do you want to create a link, do you want to show a popup? Tell us what you are targeting.

Comment: I just want to show content; text. They are meant to be shorter snippets. Bergi, I am looking now -- will let you know soon if it works!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Poof_%28The_Fairly_OddParents%29&format=json&exintro=1&redirects this link still doesn't really show "Poof" ... is it because I am only extracting "extracts" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time the part after the hash is a section title (though it is simply appended to the new URL, so it can be, and occasionally is, used to point to other kinds of anchors), so you can locate the section (with the `mobileview` action for example) and with the section index you can query the HTML for that section. (`extracts` does not support sections, so you you must use something else and enforce length limits manually.)

Answer (score 0):

The hash points to a named anchor or ID in the target document. So if you're parsing the page content, then ideally you'd find the anchor tag or ID and return the content that follows that element, rather than starting at the beginning of the content.